# FastAPI TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, fastapi

```
@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    houses = []
    for house in load:
        for imagem in house["multimedia"]["imagem"]:
            url = imagem["url"]
            
        houses.append({
            "id": house["id"],
            "titulo": house["titulo"],
            "preco": house["precoweb"],
            "url": url
             })
    return houses
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
File "./main.py", line 18, in read_root
    url = imagem["url"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

But if I instead have simply return imagem["url"] it doesn't give me the error so I don't understand where it is coming from.

Comment: What is `load` in the above code? Can you please post the full code

Comment: What does `imagem` actually contain. Any chance that you have to serialise a JSON string to a dict first?

Comment: @navneethc {
  "url": "http://media.remax.com/IMOVEIS/3070/0003C305B74F77.jpg",
  "descr": "&nbsp;",
  "principal": "0",
  "ordem": null
}

Comment: @AbhishekChaudhari load = json.load(open("data.json"))["imoveis"]["imovel"]
I also added what imagem contains in another comment.

Comment: `imagem` is a string and you cannot use another string (`"url"`) to index it.

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers imagem is not a string, its a dict: 
{ "url": "media.remax.com/IMOVEIS/3070/0003C305B74F77.jpg", 
"descr": "&nbsp;", 
"principal": "0", 
"ordem": null }

Comment: @PauloAlves This is just a case where you need to sit down and look at what structure your data actually has, and debug your application accordingly. Without posting your entire file here, noone will be able to help you. You say `imagem` is a dictionary, yet your error message clearly states that it is a string. Go from there and do the work.

Comment: @M.O.  Please see the image in the reply. Every time I try to do what the error tells me, it comes back and gives me the opposite.
Imagem is in a loop of house["multimedia"]["imagem"] so each imagem is a dict.

Comment: Are **all** entries in `house["multimedia"]["imagem"]` dicts?

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I figured it out.

In some cases imagem was a string so I simply did a conditional to check its type.

```
if type(imagem) is dict:
        url = imagem["url"]
        print(type(imagem))
else:
```